# Apply loaded spritesheet to spine skeleton instead of native atlas

Tags: pixi.js, spine

There are spine skeleton(json) and spritesheet with bundled(via texturepacker) assets from spine.
How to put assets from spritesheet into the spine instead of atlas? without loading native atlas?
**pixi.js v7.3 and pixi-spine v.4.0.4.**

It could be implemented with AtlasAttachmentLoader in earlier version of pixi. But it doesn't work in pixi 7.x.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same problem, the solution was to import that directly from this:

```
import { AtlasAttachmentLoader, SkeletonJson } from '@pixi-spine/runtime-3.8';
```

Not sure about version, but this works for me

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what "that" and "this" refer to. Can you clarify your post, please?

Comment: @AdrianMole sorry about my english.
I mean - you can just add this line to your imports and everything will be fine.